# Check if all files are available in storage - Azure ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-adf

In Azure data factory, how to check if an array of string(filenames) contains value?

I'm getting file names from get metadata activity and I need to check if all 4 filenames that I have are available in storage account before proceeding.

I'm expecting 4 files into the storage account and I need to check if all the 4 files are available. I need to explicitly check against the file names and not the number of files - this being a requirement

When I try to validate it using the child item from get meta data I am getting error `"array elements can only be selected using an integer index."` The issue here is that the file could be present at any index in the next load

Is there a better way to validate the filename?

Appreciate your help, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My get meta data output looks like this

```
 "childItems": [
    {
        "name": "1.py",
        "type": "File"
    },
    {
        "name": "SalesData.numbers",
        "type": "File"
    },
    {
        "name": "file1.txt",
        "type": "File"
    }
```

]

and i used the below expression in set variable activity to check for file names

```
@if(
contains(activity('Get Metadata1').output.childitems,
json(concat('{"name":"file1.txt"',',','"type":"File"}'))), 

if(
contains(activity('Get Metadata1').output.childitems,
json(concat('{"name":"file2.txt"',',','"type":"File"}'))),

if(
contains(activity('Get Metadata1').output.childitems,
json(concat('{"name":"2.py"',',','"type":"File"}'))),'yes','no')
,'no')
,'no')
```

this checks if my blob has file1.txt, file2.txt and 2.py

if yes, i am assigning yes to variable else no

You can use a if condition as well

Comment: thanks a lot, appreciate your help!

Comment: Glad to know. :-)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to check if multiple files exist using arrays but it is a bit fiddly.  I often pass this off to another activity in the pipeline eg Stored Procedure or Notebook activity, depending on what compute you have available in the pipeline (eg a SQL database or Spark cluster).  However if you do need to do this in the pipeline this may work for you.

To start off, I have an array parameter with the following value:

| Parameter Name | Parameter Type | Parameter Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| pFilesToCheck | Array | ["json1.json","json2.json","json3.json","json4.json"] |

These are the files that must exist.  Next I have a `Get Metadata` activity pointing at a data lake folder with the **Child Items** argument set in the Field List:

[image: Get Metadata activity]

This will return some output in this format, listing all the files in the given directory, with some additional information on the execution:

```
{
    "childItems": [
        {
            "name": "json1.json",
            "type": "File"
        },
        {
            "name": "json2.json",
            "type": "File"
        },
        {
            "name": "json3.json",
            "type": "File"
        },
        {
            "name": "json4.json",
            "type": "File"
        }
    ],
    "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime (Some Region)",
    "executionDuration": 0,
    "durationInQueue": {
        "integrationRuntimeQueue": 1
    },
    "billingReference": {
        "activityType": "PipelineActivity",
        "billableDuration": [
            {
                "meterType": "AzureIR",
                "duration": 0.016666666666666666,
                "unit": "Hours"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

In order to compare the input array `pFilesToCheck` (the files which **must** exist) with the results from the `Get Metadata` activity (the files which **do** exist), we must put them in a comparable format.  I use an Array variable to do this:

| Variable Name | Variable Type |
| --- | --- |
| arrFilenames | Array |

Next is a `For Each` activity running in **Sequential** mode and using the `range` function to loop from 0 to 3, ie the array index for each item in the `childItems` array.  The expression determines the number of items in the `Get Metadata` output
which is 0-based.  The **Items** property is set to the following expression:

```
@range(0,length(activity('Get Metadata File List').output.childItems))
```

Inside the `For Each` activity is an `Append` activity which appends the current item from the for each loop to the array variable `arrFilenames`.  It uses this expression in the **Value** property:

```
@activity('Get Metadata File List').output.childItems[item()].name
```

'@item()' in this case will be a number between 0 and 3 being generated by the `range` function mentioned above.  Once the loop is complete the array `arrFilenames` will now look like this (ie in the same format as the input array):

```
["json1.json","json2.json","json3.json","json4.json"]
```

The input array and actual file list can now be compared using the `intersection` function.  I use a `Set Variable` activity with a boolean variable to record the result:

```
@equals(
length(variables('arrFilenames')),
length(intersection(variables('arrFilenames'),pipeline().parameters.pFilesMustExist)))
```

This expression compares the *length of the array which contains the files which actually exist* with the *length of the same array joined via the intersection function to the input array of files which should exist*.  If the numbers match then all the files exist.  If the numbers do not match then **not** all the files exist.

Comment: This is a great answer. For my use case -- determining if a container contained a specified file list -- I had to adjust the final `Set Variable` to: `@equals(
length(pipeline().parameters.pFilesMustExist),
length(intersection(variables('arrFilenames'),pipeline().parameters.pFilesMustExist)))`

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this (Python)?

```
import fnmatch
import os
 
rootPath = '/'
pattern = '*.mp3'
 
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootPath):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):
        print( os.path.join(root, filename))
```

Comment: Python is not supported as ADF takes dynamic expression.